# How to create an R method

Tags: r, methods, range

I'm not familiar with R methods, I want to create a method "format" with R

```
format <- function(object,...){
}
```

the input "object" is an object from class `player`, which is a data frame with 3 columns: `attributes`, `weights`, and the assigned values.

Here is the structure of the data frame:

```
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(attribute = c("Acceleration/speed", "Dribbling", 
"Aggression", "Ball Control", "Composure", "Crossing"), weights = c(0.174119699170201, 
0.0142504648411431, 0, 0.0821275086888316, 0, 0.079118689094399
), values = list(82.5, 88, 84, 92, 86, 90)), .Names = c("attribute", 
"weights", "values"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("player", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have numerical and categorical attributes. For the numerical attributes, I want to check if the values are within the range [0,100] (check the values and remove anything not compliant) and for the categorical attributes, I want to convert them to factors and to check if they are ordered with the appropriate levels. For example factor(`high`, `levels = c("low", "medium", "high")`.

Comment: Numeric values and factors are logically very different "things", what are you trying to do such that they are dealt with like this? (BTW: simple vectors cannot combine numbers and factors in the same vector.)

Comment: As @r2evans said, numeric values and factors are very different. It's hard to see how one function should handle both cases. What do u actually need to do here? Do you need to alter the values if it's not in the range [0,100]? Do you need to sort the factor variable? Or do you just need a boolean for control flow? Also, are these lists? vectors? Data frames? Matrices? Arrays? tibbles? Without a sample dataset or a more detailed explanation, it's hard to help.

Comment: What do you mean by "check" for [0,100]? Do you mean to filter the data and return only values within that range? Or do you mean to return a vector of boolean (`logical` in R-speak) that indicates if a value is within the range?

Comment: @r2evans  , I explain, the object passed in the parameter of the method "format" is an object from class player: which is data.frame with 2 columns : attributes and their assigned values. I have numerical and categorical attributes. For the numerical attributes, I want to check if the values are within the range [0,100] (TRUE or FALSE) and for the categorical attributes , I want to convert them to factors and to check if they are ordered with the appropriate levels. For example factor("high", levels = c("low", "medium", "high"). Thanks for helping

Comment: *What do you mean by **"check"**?* To me, you could mean "check the values and remove anything not compliant", or you might mean "check the values and return a vector of logicals to report which are compliant". Please include a sample of your data by copying the output from `dput(head(x))`, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55839850/edit) your question, and paste in there. I must say that SO is not meant to be a tutorial site, and this seems very much like something covered in basic R programming tutorials. If you have code you have tried, you need to include that as well.

Comment: @r2evans, done , my aim is how to create an R method (not a function). I could create an R function that check the numeric values are within [0,100] and to convert categorical features to factors. But I am note familiar with methods and I couldn't find any helpful example. A simple syntax example  could help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the sample data, though I confess I am more confused now than before. You asked for a "method", which can be confused with "function", supported by the fact that your question had a template of `format <- function(...)`. So you're talking about a "functional-property" (as opposed to a "value-property", improper terms, I know) of a `data.frame`, is that it? R doesn't generally do that until you go into one of the various OO techniques (including R4 and R6), and at that point you start losing much of its `data.frame` transparency.

Comment: I see thanks. I am thinking of using "UseMethod()" inside the function. Something similar to :                                                                                     
   mean <- function (x, ...) {
   UseMethod("mean", x)
 }

Comment: Hmm, so you really do need a method -- not a function. Have you read Advanced R? It has several chapters on OO programming, so maybe it has some helpful info? https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html

Comment: Most (all?) "methods" are really just functions that are meant to override how a "normal/base" function deals with a data type that is either (a) completely customized, different from others, or (b) really just another type (e.g., frame) but the meaning of that data is meaningful to you. So what base function are you trying to mimic and/or over-ride with your version of the method?